SQL update query sometimes too slow
When update statement, the execute time sometime taking 60 second sometimes taking 1-2 sec. Total row count around 18 million. CARDID is our PK. Almost each 2-3 sec our system send a request to that query. You can find the query on below;
    UPDATE C
    SET
        [CARDTYPE]           =  @NEWCARDTYPE,
        [ICPGROUPID]         =  @NEWICPGROUPID,
        [CARDNUMBER]         =  @NEWCARDNUMBER,
        [PINCODE]            =  @NEWPINCODE,
        [SCODE]              =  @NEWSCODE,
        [STATUS]             =  @NEWSTATUS,
        [CUSTOMERID]         =  @NEWCUSTOMERID,
        [PROFILEID]          =  @NEWPROFILEID,
        [BALANCE]            =  @NEWBALANCE,
        [BALANCETYPE]        =  @NEWBALANCETYPE,
        [DECIMALS]           =  @NEWDECIMALS,
        [CURRENCY]           =  @NEWCURRENCY,
        [STARTDATE]          =  @NEWSTARTDATE,
        [EXPIRATIONDATE]     =  @NEWEXPIRATIONDATE,
        [PINCOUNT]           =  @NEWPINCOUNT,
        [PINDATE]            =  @NEWPINDATE,
        [INITIALPIN]         =  @NEWINITIALPIN,
        [INITIALSCODE]       =  @NEWINITIALSCODE,
        [UPDATEDATE]         =  GETDATE(),
        [ACTIVATIONDATE]     =  @NEWACTIVATIONDATE,
        [REGISTERDATE]       =  @NEWREGISTERDATE,
        [UNREGISTERDATE]     =  @NEWUNREGISTERDATE,
        [ORDERID]            =  @NEWORDERID,
        [RELATEDCARD]        =  @NEWRELATEDCARD,
        [LOADCOUNT]          =  @NEWLOADCOUNT,
        [REDEEMCOUNT]        =  @NEWREDEEMCOUNT,
        [ISCHANGED]          =  1,
        [ISPROCESSED]        =  0
    FROM dbo.[CARD] C 
    WHERE
        CARDID = @CARDID

Also we have some indexes on the that table. What can we do? We are really stuck. We added one filter more but it did not work.


maybe 1 combined index can repalce all the idnexes or at least a great part

"...sometime taking 60 second sometimes taking 1-2 sec..." -- In SQL Server there's a big difference between wait time (when the query is waiting for locks to be release and doing nothing really) and actual execution time. I would suggest you check if 59 out of those 60 seconds are "wait time" or not. If that's the case, then the problem is in other queries that are locking rows.

Get a query plan, then you can see the bottleneck. You can use CTRL-L on SSMS or select the icon "Actual Query Plan" then execute your query. It most probably advice you to create an index, examine the index it advices and change it to cover the most of your needs (if necessary).
One possible reason could be, sometime another user may query or update on the same table and your update query waits for it to finish.

@endo64 Not entirely clear, but inferring from index names in the image he likely already has the best index for this query. It's almost certainly the 2nd part (locking).

Is there any index on column CARDID? The fast results are caused probably to already cashed IDs. If you clear cashe you probably have delays all the time.

is @CARDID of same type as the CARDID column?

I don't have much confidence in the design which we cannot see, due to the fact that this query updates fields that are typically only written to upon INSERT, such as [REGISTEREDATE], [INITIALPIN]. Also the schema is suspect, with fields like [ORDERID] in a table that kinda-sorta represents a customer master list or a "card" master list. Perhaps there is a lot of wait time because entire rows are being updated in all tables of the system, instead of just the fields that logically should be updated?

@siggemannen yes, it same type BIGINT.

@Emka yes there is. It is clustered. Also that field is primary key.

this query run for the same solution on 2 different servers. A new request post almost every second. Requests can posting through different methods. In other words, the updated fields are not actually the same for every request.

@HardCode we will try it on.

@HardCode it did not work. When tried to update for 11 fields and again there was high transaction time.

Updates, deletes, inserts have to update all the indexes on each action. From the inputs I can only suggest to remove all indexes except the PK and see if it helps. If it helps but you may not remove the indexes because you use them by some selects, then you at least know what is the issue :) Maybe you can really leave only 2-3 necessary indexes.
18 million rows are actually not a big deal especially if you query by id. Is it possible that this update query executed by multiple clients at the same time? That could explain the execution time difference. I also suggest to run some profiler and see what exactly happens on the server and what are actual query execution times. Maybe they are fast and the issue is somewhere else.

You have not provided DDL so we cannot tell what columns allow nulls.
As well as the potential non-clustered index problems, if a column goes from a small size value to a larger sized value, and there is not enough space on the page, a page split could occur which might end up moving a lot a pages which obviously takes time. A good starting point for avoiding expansive updates is to use dummy values, not NULLs, for unknown values when inserting.

If you are updating every 3 seconds this dataset, I am guessing that you are selecting it even more often. Index wise just one clustered on the primary key is enough, so I believe you having locks from the select statements and the update just waiting for it's turn.
Some possible solution are:

Use no lock on the select statement
Make the Select statement on cashed results
Make the update statement asynchronous

But in general, you have to review your approach in general. Since this sounds more like a business problem rather than system.
